# Deleting Duplicates in array and replacing them with unused values

Tags: c, arrays

My objective for this program is to let the user determine the size of the array and dynamically allocate memory for whatever size they choose. Once the user defines the size of the array, random numbers that do no exceed the size of the array are placed into all of the allotted positions. Where I am having issues is removing duplicates from the array and replacing them with a value that is not being used,
Example:

```
Please enter the size of the array:

User Input: 5 

Output of code: 5, 3, 3, 1, 2
```

**I would need it to be something like this:**

```
Please enter the size of the array:

User Input: 3

Output of program: 3, 1, 2
```

Currently reading "C Programming - A Modern Approach" by K.N. King (Second Edition).

if someone could point me in the right direction on how to approach this, it would be much appreciated.Here is my code thus far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define true 1
#define false 0

typedef int bool;


int main() {

int *UserData;
int TempPost;
int replace;
int UserInput;
int i;
int result;
bool digit_seen[UserInput];
int digit;
srand ((unsigned) time(NULL));

printf("Please enter the size of the array using a whole number: \n");
scanf("%d", &UserInput);


UserData = malloc(sizeof(int) * (UserInput ) +1);


 for(i=0; i < UserInput; i ++) {

    result = (( rand() % UserInput) + 1);

 }

    // check for duplicate values while putting values in array

    while(UserInput>0){

        digit = UserInput % UserInput;
          if(digit_seen[digit])
              break;

          digit_seen[digit] = true;
          UserInput /= UserInput;

          if(UserInput > 0)
              printf("Repeated digit \n");
          else
              printf("No repeated digit \n");


    }

  // Sorting the array using a Bubble sort

        while(1){

            replace = 0;


            for (i=0; i<(UserInput - 1); i++){


                if(UserData[i]>UserData[i+1]){

                    TempPost = UserData[i];
                    UserData[i] = UserData[i+1];
                    UserData[i+1] = TempPost;

                    replace = 1;


                }


            }


          if(replace==0){

              break;
          } 



        }

    printf("%d \n", result);



 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you need to generate an array of N containing a random permutation of numbers 1 to N? This is how your requirement sounds, and not the whole mess you have described.

Comment: @EugeneSh. yes that would be correct I believe my code segment accomplishes that.

Comment: ..or {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,..n}, pick a random number index from [0..n-1], take out the value there, if index not [n-1], move number at [n-1] down to that position, then go back and pick from [n-2].. rinse, repeat.

Comment: @xing I am not sure if I could approach it that way mainly because my initial post doesn't mention it but after I fill all the positions with unused values I need to sort them (without a library function). Not sure if that makes sense or not.

Comment: Why without a library function? Is this homework?

Comment: @MartinJames not sure if I understand what you mean, would you mind elaborating a little more please?

Comment: Why do you add 1 to `UserInput`?

Comment: @xing  yes one of the 3's would be replaced with a 4.

Comment: @Barmar I thought when doing modulus in c program gives all the values of whatever is being modded minus 1 so that is why I added it. Like if i did rand() % 6 it would only give me random numbers between 0-5 and adding the 1 would give me the six. Is this not correct?

Comment: [Fisher-Yates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) is "more random" than the one proposed. Or more uniform, strictly speaking.

Comment: @xing so essentially what you are saying is if the user defines the array at 9 enter numbers in a sequential order from 0-8, shuffle them, then when the user asks me to sort them again just do the opposite?

Comment: @JosephV I meant why are you adding 1 when you do the `malloc()`.

Comment: @Barmar All the examples for the rand function that I have seen have used the plus 1 I just assumed that is what I do. Can you do it without it when using malloc()?

Comment: My question had nothing to do with the rand function. I wondered why you add 1 here: `malloc(sizeof(int) * (UserInput +1));` That's making the array larger than you need.

Comment: Sorry @Barmar I misread you comment. I was using some examples from my previous programs that used malloc() and the plus 1 was for the null terminating character, except I didn't need that, sorry about that. I completely missed that.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the most efficient way, but you can do it as you're generating the random numbers. When you pick a random number, go through all the previous elements of the array and see if it's already been used. Keep looping until you pick an unused number.

```
for (i = 0; i < UserInput; i++) {
    do {
        result = ( rand() % UserInput) + 1;
    } while (in_array(result, UserData, i-1));
    UserData[i] = result;
}


int in_array(int val, int* array, int array_size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++) {
        if (array[i] == val) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

A slightly more efficient way to do it is to initialize the array to `0`. Then instead of picking random numbers, pick a random index to fill in, and repeat this until you pick an index that contains `0`.

```
UserData = calloc(UserInput, sizeof(int));
for (i = 1; i <= UserInput; i++) {
    int index;
    do {
        index = rand() % UserInput;
    } while (UserData[index] != 0)
    UserData[index] = i;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Barmar going to assume it is not efficient because it takes more time to accomplish it this way? What is a way you think is more efficient?

Comment: The most efficient way is to fill in the array from 1 to n, then randomly shuffle the array.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you why did you use calloc instead of malloc? Sorry I am still new to this.

Comment: `calloc()` automatically zeros the memory.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is shuffle the array instead. Just fill the array with all the numbers in order using a simple for loop, then shuffle it with something like this:

```
//read user input
//create array and fill with all the numbers in order
//[0,1,2,3,4,5 .. ... ]
int index, temp;

// size is the size of the array
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    index = rand()%size;//random place to pick from
    temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[index];
    array[index] = temp;
}
```

This is a lot more effecient -and less error prone- than your current approach.